# Create an item on the FLY and pass it to the form, Why only single line of text fields will be populated

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

I want to implement a Copy Item functionality >> so inside my Gallery i added a Copy icon >> with this OnSelect, where I am trying to create a variable on the fly, as follow:-

```
Set(newExpiry,
{Title:Gallery1_1.Selected.Title,
'Sales Program ID':{Value:Gallery1_1.Selected.'Sales Program ID'},
'Effective Date':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Effective Date',
'End Date.':Gallery1_1.Selected.'End Date.',
'New End Date':Gallery1_1.Selected.'New End Date'
,Amount:Gallery1_1.Selected.Amount,
'Accrual Amount':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Accrual Amount',
'Payment Type':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Payment Type',
'Product Code':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Product Code',
'Item Rebate Group':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Item Rebate Group',
'Requested By':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Requested By',
'Date Requested':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Date Requested',
'Date of Expiry Requested':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Date of Expiry Requested',
'Additional Comments':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Additional Comments',

'Program Entered By':Gallery1_1.Selected.'Program Entered By',
Approver:Gallery1_1.Selected.Approver,
IsCopy:{Value:"True"}
});   
EditForm(ExpiryForm);Navigate(ExpiryCRUD);
```

and on the ExpiryCRUD Form >> I defined this formula inside the items:-

```
If(!IsBlank(newExpiry),newExpiry,If(varExpiryID>0 ,LookUp('Rebate Expiry Form',ID=varExpiryID),If(!IsBlank(varSetupID),LookUp('Rebate Expiry Form',RealtedFormID=varSetupID))))
```

Currently only the text (single line of text) field will be per-populated based on the variable i created on the fly .. any advice on this? while Date fields, People/group fields and choice fields are not going to be per-polutated ..